# Classic asp paging and session state

Tags: visual-studio-2008, session, asp-classic, paging

Working on a classic asp page that uses paging.  The error I am having a problem with is this:  Lets say that you have 5 pages returned in your record set and you are on page 2.  You leave and come back, you then press the link for page 3, the trouble is your session has timed out.  I don't know why this happens but the page is reloaded, but the session check is bypassed and of course when the page attempts to retrieve the record set the session variables are now empty so I am getting a message stating: error near ',' line 1, because now the query is defunct.  How do I get around this?

Thanks, Ron.

Answer (score 0):

You can just check if any session variable is empty and redirect user to the first page or login page (if you have it).